# Cannot start mean.io, "Error: dependency 'access' was not registered"

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

UPDATE: Solved due to updates, see [this](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/736).

---

I'm brand new to mean.io.

I have followed the [install instructions](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) for mean.io, except for the [gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) that let's you install node without sudo (since I really don't care about this machine I'm working on).

Everything went well, even "grunt", until I go to myipaddress:3000, where I get a "page is not available" and this on the grunt:

```
/home/.../myApp/node_modules/dependable/index.js:115
        throw new Error("dependency '" + name + "' was not registered");
              ^
Error: dependency 'access' was not registered
    at get (/home/.../myApp/node_modules/dependable/index.js:115:15)
```

This is [the myApp/node_modules/dependable/index.js file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/randwa1k/3df2db3c32ebfc43bb43/raw/4e87953997519c6af1da388728d13058e79ce8f6/index.js).

Here are the directories at myApp:

```
myApp$ ls
AUTHORS           config         LICENSE       packages   server.js
bower_components  Gruntfile.js   node_modules  Procfile
bower.json        karma.conf.js  package.json  README.md
```

I tried `bower install --allow-root'` from [this]
(https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/673), but I still get the error.

=====

Update:

I don't know what's going on here. Sometimes it works sometimes it errors (for `grunt`, so far so good with `node server` starts). Sometimes the error is

```
/home/username/201408meanio/myapp/node_modules/dependable/index.js:115
    throw new Error("dependency '" + name + "' was not registered");
Error: dependency 'access' was not registered
at get (/home/username/201408meanio/myapp/node_modules/dependable/index.js:115:15)
...
```

So I tried installing mean.io on a new user account following the README instructions from the start, step by step, I faced the **404 Error: Failed to lookup view "404" in views directory** problem, described [here](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/680).

So like they said, I increased Gruntfile.js's livereload interval, and things started working if I run `grunt` ... sometimes, has not worked so far for `node server`.

Comment: Since you said grunt is working i assume you already executed `npm install` in your Project-Dir - but did it work without any errors? Maybe try it again (I also had a case yesterday where I needed to execute it twice)

Comment: Thank you so much Charminbear. Yes it works after I logged out and logged back in. :)  I didn't even have to run `npm install`, wonder why that happened.